# Auto Class Generator

Tags: c++, class, templates, code-generation, auto-generate

I had originally asked this question here: [Former Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162554/an-in-code-class-auto-generator-from-a-string-of-text-or-some-other-mechanism?noredirect=1#comment85331027_49162554)

It appears that what I was asking for was misunderstood. I will try to make this as clear and as brief as possible:

---

I'm working on a parser that will automatically generate a `c++` `class` and if the names of the header and cpp files are present the parser will write out those files respectively. If they are omitted then the parser will not write any files where it will generate a class automatically based on the information that is pulled in from the file.

What I don't know how to do: Let's say my class's identifier is stored in a `std::string` how can I extract the text in the string to use that as the class's name. For example:

```
{ 
    std::string className( "Foo" );

    // parser writing class in code
    class className { ....

}
```

This is what I don't know how to do if it can even be done. As stated in my previous question I prefer to stay away from `macros` but wouldn't mind using `templates` if needed or some other mechanism.

---

**Conclusion**

After reading the comments and the provided answer below; my initial assumption that I didn't mention was in fact proven true. It can not be done. I was suspicious of this, but only wanted to confirm. So this does leave me in having to write out to files in order to create the needed header and or source files at run time.

Comment: You can't - the name of a class musrt be known at compile-time. Your design is wrong.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I understand that much yes. But that is why I did mention `templates` if they could be used.

Comment: Templates are compile-time things too. You appear to want to create classes at run-time, which is not possible in C++.

Comment: So it appears that I have to resort to `writing out to files only`.

Comment: I think the best you can do here is a pre-build step that generates the code.  We used such a thing to build a resource class from a folder of files on a project some years ago.

Comment: No idea what you mean by that. It's highly unlikely that whatever  your problem is it hasn't been solved many times before. I don't see why you think you need to autogenerate anything - autogeneration is almost always a severe code smell.

Comment: A bit off topic, but perhaps it is time for you to look into Lisp (Common-Lisp, Clojure, ...). These sort of things are natural to lispy languages. Also, perhaps you should use Bison as your parser. If you rework the problem, Bison may be the tool needed

Comment: I don't understand the question. *"my class's identifier"* Do you mean class name? *"how can I extract the text"* Extract from where?

Comment: I believe OP wants to do something like Perl's `eval "sub foo { print \"Hi.\"; }"; foo();`, to define names during a running program. But C++ doesn't have a thing like `eval`.

Comment: @aschepler I don't know Perl so I can't say if it's similar or not, but I do appreciate the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

C++ programs cannot modify themselves.

If you want to auto-generate C++ code, do it as an pre-compilation step in your build process.

I myself have a nice Python script generating a ton of C++ classes (and their accompanying boilerplate) each representing one of several "message types" defined by a third party. It's lovely.

Comment: I myself am using common-lisp more often :D

Comment: @Makketronix: Hopefully it's not contagious :)

Comment: @ LRO No, but addictive!

Comment: I wasn't fully sure if it could be done or not (even with template meta programming); but my initial assumption was no. Now it is fully confirmed. Thank You!

Comment: @FrancisCugler: No problem.